# Proving the sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $S$. Where $S$ is a metric subspace. Given that every convergent subsequence of $\{x_{k(n)}\}$ converges to the same point say $x$. Prove that if S is compact, show that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Compactness seems irrelevant here. Try the contrapositive: Assume that $\{x_n\}$ does *not* converge to $x$, and see where that leads.

Comment: definitely relevant. Consider what happens if S is not compact

Comment: Compactness gives that each subsequence has a convergent subsequence. Now proceed as @Harald suggested.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Try $x_n=n$ in $S=\mathbb R$. There is no convergent subsequence hence the hypothesis holds.

Comment: What does "every convergent subsequence of $x_{k(n)}$" mean? What is $k(n)$?

Comment: $k(n): \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Mathematics: No, did you mean "every convergent subsequence $x_{k(n)}$" or is $k(n)$ fixed?

Comment: Ooops, I had missed the word “convergent” in the problem statement.

Comment: the former one, $k(n)$ is not fixed

Comment: @Mathematics: I think you should edit your question, because it is otherwise misleading in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume we're in a metric space with metric $d$.

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $x$.  Then $\exists \, \epsilon > 0$ and a sequence of positive integers $m_1,m_2,\ldots$ such that $d(x, x_{m_i})\geq \epsilon$ for all positive integers $i$.  The sequence $\{ x_{m_i}\}$ has a convergent subsequence because $S$ is compact.  This subsequence converges to $x$, but that's a contradiction because no term in this subsequence is within $\epsilon$ of $x$.

Comment: I think it should be a metric space

Answer (score 1):

Every subsequent converges to the same point if S is compact and hence every subsequence are converges and converge to the same points and hence the sequence also convergent to x. Is the proof valid?

Comment: I’m afraid not; I’m not sure that it even makes sense. Compactness of $S$ is needed to ensure that $\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has any convergent subsequences at all. The hypothesis then says that all of these convergent subsequences have the same limit, $x$. Finally, one argues as @littleO did: if the sequence doesn’t converge to $x$, it has a subsequence bounded away from $x$, and compactness of $S$ implies that this subsequence has a convergent limit. This limit must be different from $x$, and we get a contradiction.

Comment: Compactness ensures that the subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ is convergent and from the question mentioned, every convergent subsequence converge to the same point. That's why every convergent subsequence converge to the same point and hence the sequence$\{x_n\}_n$

Comment: You’re still trying to make it simpler than it actually is. Compactness only ensures that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has at least one convergent subsequence. Then the hypotheses of the problem tell you that all of its convergent subsequences converge to $x$. But it still takes some work to prove that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ itself is convergent. You really do need littleO’s argument or something equivalent to it; you can’t just declare that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges.

Comment: What about if i use the theorem that any compact subset is complete, is it work in this way?

Comment: No. You really do need to use the argument that littleO gave and I repeated in an earlier comment.